# CSS Background Colour of Specific Tab

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

HTML

```
<div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">
   <ul class="tabs wc-tabs">
       <li class="paym-plans_tab">
          <a href="#tab-paym-plans">Contract Deals</a>
       </li>
          <li class="simfree-plans_tab active">
```

CSS

```
#tabs ul.wooTabs li a.selected, #tabs ul.tabs li.active a, .woocommerce_tabs ul.tabs li.active a, .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li.active a {
    background: #52b9e9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: white;
}
```

Trying to change background colour of specific woocommerce tabs `.paym-plans_tab active` and `.simfree-plans_tab active` to `#52b9e9` and text colour to white only whilst the tab is selected the CSS above changes all tabs how can I target just the tabs I want.

Comment: If you only want to change the colour on the currently "selected" tab you will probably require a JavaScript solution.

Comment: but the tab has its own class is there no way to target it

Comment: If I understand you correctly then I don't think so, since some logic would be necessary to keep track of which tab is "selected". You could add an onclick() JavaScript function to the tabs that works by clearing all tabs to the "unselected" colour and then setting the selected one to the "selected" colour.

Comment: but when each tab is selected it changes to `.class active` as you can see in the HTML

Comment: In that case you can create a new CSS block for `li.active` specifying the new colours.

Comment: I have been trying to solve this for days, what do I need to do?

Comment: Do you have some logic running to determine which class should be .active?

Comment: It is woocommerce when I click a tab the class changes to .class active when selected.

Comment: take a look at the page if that will help http://mobilereactor.co.uk/shop/mobile-phones/google-nexus-6-32gb-blue-deals/

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you need just something like:

```
.wc-tabs .active a {
    background: #52b9e9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: white;
}
```

Of course your framework should assign `active` class to a tab when you click it and remove it from previously active one

Comment: Could you provide more info on that? Why it is not easy? Could you provide a sample with that woocommerce? Most of us don't have it on our workstations and it would be much easier if we can try it online and share the result

Comment: http://mobilereactor.co.uk/shop/mobile-phones/google-nexus-6-32gb-blue-deals/ you can view the page source of the tabs in question.

Comment: should be able to access it now i have disabled the maintenance mode

Comment: Thanks, I tried to achieve that on your site and updated the answer (added `a` to the selector), please try it. It sets the URL styles to what you asked for

Comment: I updated the CSS to  `.simfree-plans_tab .active a {
    background: #52b9e9 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    color: white !important;
}` and the sim free tab is still the same colour, this is my problem lol

Comment: Try `document.querySelector(".simfree-plans_tab .active a")` in console and see that it selects nothing. So you can try to substitute the text in the quotes with everything that people propose and see the result :)

Comment: What I just did - set the background with `document.querySelector(".wc-tabs .active a").style = "background: #52b9e9 none repeat scroll 0 0; color: white;"
"background: #52b9e9 none repeat scroll 0 0; color: white;"`. Of course it sets the style for currently selected item only and you need to reset it manually after the tab is changed but it'll work automatically if you add that record to the CSS file :)

Comment: I can definatly select `.simfree-plans_tab.active > a` with firebug, but the colours wont change ??? it's so annoying thanks for your help though i'm gonna go ask the author.

Answer (score 1):

see [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/cbbbmro0/3/)

```
.paym-plans_tab {
  background-color: #52b9e9;
  color: white;
  }

.paym-plans_tab > a {
  color: white;
 }

.simfree-plans_tab > a {
   color: white;
  }


a:hover {
 background-color: red;
}

.simfree-plans_tab {
  background-color: #52b9e9;
  color: white;
 }
```

Comment: this changes the colour behind the tab